# Android Studio Error Cannot Resolve Symbol 'Extra Message'

Tags: android

I have made a quiz program, where when I click on something in a list, it goes to a new class, with an intent extra.

```
if (quiznumber.equals("Quiz One")){
                        String message = "Quiz One";
                        Intent gotosetone = new Intent(QuizSelectionActivity.this, CoolQuizActivity.class);
                        gotosetone.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                        startActivity(gotosetone);
                    }else if (quiznumber.equals("Quiz Two")){
                        String message = "Quiz Two";
                        Intent gotosettwo = new Intent(QuizSelectionActivity.this, CoolQuizActivity.class);
                        gotosettwo.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                        startActivity(gotosettwo);
```

so I have an error at the next class, coolquizactivity, which looks like this

```
 Intent gotosetone = getIntent();
    String message = gotosetone.getStringExtra(QuizSelectionActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    Intent gotosettwo = getIntent();
    String message2 = gotosetone.getStringExtra(QuizSelectionActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

but the EXTRA_MESSAGE is red, and says, Cannot resolve symbol, EXTRA_MESSAGE

Can someone post a picture of how to fix this?
thanks

(btw, there was already a question on this, and there was an answer, but I couldn't figure out how to to fix it, and I couldn't ask for a picture, cause I have 1 reputation and I can't even comment!)

Comment: it must be `public static`....

Comment: Add more Code of QuizSelectionActivity and CoolQuizActivity in above question

Comment: k, ill edit it :D

Comment: Hi Daniel, does this problem still persist after below answers?

Comment: yes, it does! :(

Comment: @Daniel Still this issue EXTRA_MESSAGE is red, and says, Cannot resolve symbol, EXTRA_MESSAGE?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare EXTRA_MESSAGE as

```
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE="mystring";
```

With 'public static' keyword you can access this string variable from other class without creating an object like

```
    QuizSelectionActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Daniel elaborating Opiatefuchs comment with code and reasons. `EXTRA_MESSAGE` is red because it's declared in `QuizSelectionActivity` and `CoolQuizActivity` does not have access to it. So one way to solve this is to make it `public static` which means variable `EXTRA_MESSAGE` will now be accessible to the entire application. So in code this is how it would look

```
public class QuizSelectionActivity extends Activity {

     public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra_message";

     public void someFunction() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(QuizSelectionActivity.this, CoolQuizActivity.class);
         String message = ""; // default value
          if (quiznumber.equals("Quiz One")){
                    message = "Quiz One";
                }else if (quiznumber.equals("Quiz Two")){
                    message = "Quiz Two";
           }

           intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
           startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

and the other class `CoolQuizActivity` would consume it like this
public class CoolQuizActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         // this is the message passed "Quiz One" or "Quiz Two"
         String message = intent.getStringExtra(QuizSelectionActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

           // do action using the message passed
     }
}
```

Note use of `final` while declaring the key in `QuizSelectionActivity` which means its a constant cannot be changed.
Hope it helps you.